Modify variable value in custom hibernate validator
I use custom hibernate validator to check the format of date string, however, in some cases, I need to fall back on incorrect date(depending on the switch in the database), which generate a valid date and set it into the original field being checked. Is there any good way to do this?
Changing the first parameter of method isValid didn't work
My custom validator is just like this:
public class MyValidator implements Constraint<DateCheck, String>{
    private final String switch;
    @Override
    public void initialize(DateCheck constraintAnnotation){
        /* read the switch value in database */
        swtich = ...
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String dateString, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        boolean validFlag = false;
        validFlag = /* code checking the format of dateString */
        if(!validFlag && "OFF".equals(switch){
            /* if the date format is incorrect and the switch is "OFF", log it
            LogWriter.info("............");
            /* here I want to change the original date string, but how?*/
            ...
        } else{
            return validFlag;
        }
    }
}


"Is there any good way to do this?" Yes, by not doing it in validator. You should correct value before it hit Hibernate.
